# Gradle Incremental Tasks: Adding already generated code to the classpath

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have created a custom Gradle task that generates some java code. To optimize execution this plugin uses the @InputDirectory and @OutputDirectory annotations, so that the code does not have to  be generated each build.

However, I *do* want this task to add the generated code to the classpath. I am currently doing this by

```
class JaxbTask extends DefaultTask {
    @OutputDirectory
    File destdir = project.file( "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/mygen" )
    @InputDirectory
    File schemaRoot = project.file("${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources/myschema/")

    @TaskAction
    def main() {
        ..
        project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += destdir
        ..
    }
```

The problem is that the TaskAction is not executed and the sourcedirectory is not added to the compile path when the generated code is up to date. Is there any way to make sure that the modification of the sourcepath is always performed?

Comment: Why don't you define a jaxb source set and add it to the java source set? Alternatively you could use an existing jaxb plugin for gradle.

Comment: I would like the task to be as self-contained as possible. Actually, my destdir is dynamically extended by the name of the instantiated task by default ( File destdir = project.file( "${project.buildDir}/generated-sources/${name}" ))  As for existing plugins, I have not found a Gradle JaxB plugin hosted by an established repository (I want my build to work 3 years from now), could you point me in a good direction?

Comment: Update: It seems that some of the plugins I have found also are available via Bintray. Newbie question: Is this a repository that I can trust being available for a long time, such as mavencentral?

Comment: JCenter (Bintray) is a superset of maven and is the new preferred repository of gradle, so I would say yes.

Answer (score 0):

A task should never try to configure the build model. Configuration is the responsibility of build scripts and plugins, and needs to happen in the *configuration phase* (before any task has run).